# Javascript re-execution for a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript

I am making a Javascript bookmark for the Minecraft 1.12.2 server called **2B2T.org** using the 2b2t.dev/LolRiTTeRBot api for this currently i just redirect them to the users page but soon i will change that does anyone know how to do this

```js
alert("2B2T Player Lookup")
// is were i want to repeat too
var player = prompt("Please put the name of who you want to find","popbob")
if (player == null) {
  alert("INVALID INPUT")
  // I need some code ir repeat code or to the variable prompt
} else {
  open("https://api.2b2t.dev/seen?username=" + player)
  open("https://api.2b2t.dev/stats?username=" + player)
}
```

Comment: _"does anyone know how to do this"_ - do what?

Comment: do a re-execute the code from the top of a different spot

Comment: different spot? If you need to be able to re-execute this code, why not put it into a function?

Comment: okay i will try that

Comment: Nope did not work

Comment: I can assure you functions do work. There are likely many other things that are not happening as expected. Please edit the question to include a [mcve] otherwise we can't answer the question